# How to export a Joomla 3 component to another Joomla site?

Tags: joomla, export, components, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have lost the installation zip file of one of the component that I installed in one site. How do i export it and repackage it so i can install it in another site?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the component's manifest file is current, you can use the Extension Exporter that I wrote recently:
https://github.com/GreenCape/extension-export/releases

If you have installed additional languages, you can add them to the manifest file manually; they will then be included in the export automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but when i tried to enable that plugin, the whole site broke. Front and backend seeing a 500 error. Currently in Joomla 3.7 and 3.8.

Comment: Sorry for that - I'll have a look at it later today. Would you mind to provide me with data that helps me to track it down on the issue tracker (PHP and Joomla versions, extensions and so on)?

Comment: Added a new issue:
https://github.com/GreenCape/extension-export/issues/8

Comment: Error 500 went away when updated to Joomla 3.8.5 from 3.6.5.

Comment: Was able to export an component. But when installed at another site and going to the component page i see another error: 1146 Table 'www_mysite_com.#__storelocator_cats' doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you for creating an issue! See my comment on https://github.com/GreenCape/extension-export/issues/9 for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my comment: https://github.com/GreenCape/extension-export/issues/9

Comment: Can I use ftp to copy the sql folder from one site to another without using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Let's keep the conversation on GitHub - this is not the right place. Thank you!

Comment: I just installed and used this on my site for a component and a plugin and as far as I can tell so far it worked perfectly for both. Thanks!